# How to get value from JTABLE and pass it to the text fields after the JTable is refresh in java eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jtable

`enter code here`NO ERRORS. it works fine when the table is not refreshed but when i search an item and the table refreshes, when i click a column from the table it wont pass to the text fields. please help me. Thanks. :)

```
reloadData();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
        table.setModel(model);
        TableColumn column;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setMaxWidth(1000);
        }

//get value from JTABLE and pass it to the text fields
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1)
        {
            try{

                JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                String table_click =(target.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
                 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://;Database='';user='';password='';";
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
                ResultSet rs = null;
                PreparedStatement pst =null;
                 // Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            String sql ="select * from inventory where Id='"+table_click+"'";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
              rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                textField.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
                textField_1.setText(rs.getString("Category"));
                textField_2.setText(rs.getString("Brand"));
                textField_3.setText(rs.getString("Price"));
                textField_4.setText(rs.getString("ExDate"));
                textField_5.setText(rs.getString("Tags"));
                textField_6.setText(rs.getString("Barcode"));
                textField_8.setText(rs.getString("Id"));
            }
            }catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        }
        });

        //SEARCH
        btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String value1=textField_7.getText();
                 try{

                     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                     String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://;Database='';user='';password='';";
                     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
                   PreparedStatement pst =null;
                        //Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

                     //PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from inventory where Id=? or Name=? ");
                    String sql ="select * from inventory where CAST(Id as NVARCHAR(50))=? or Name=? ";
                    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.setString(1, textField_7.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, textField_7.getText());


                 ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                 if(value1.equals("")){
                      reloadData();
                      model.fireTableDataChanged();
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter a Name or Id of the Item","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                  }else{  


                              table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
              }

                       }


                 catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}

            }


        });

        }

//Table with SQL
    private void reloadData() {

        columnNames.clear();
            data.clear();
         try {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://;Database='';user='';password='';";
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from inventory");
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }   
                data.addElement(row);
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
         table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
            scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are losing your MouseListener because you are creating a new JTable.

In your `reloadData()` method. Don't create a new JTable. Instead create a new TableModel and then just use:

```
table.setModel( theNewModel );
```

Also,

```
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

never invoke a fireXXX() method directly. That is the job of the TableModel to invoke the appropriate method.

Comment: how will i do that? sorry quite new here. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Your code already uses the variables "data" and "columnName" to create the JTable. Instead of creating a JTable using those variables, you can create a DefaultTableModel using the same varaibles. NOte, there is also no need to reset the viewport of the scrollpane either.